# Ruby IO#read max length for single read

Tags: ruby, io

How can i determine the max length IO#read can get in a single read on the current platform?

```
irb(main):301:0> File.size('C:/large.file') / 1024 / 1024
=> 2145
irb(main):302:0> s = IO.read 'C:/large.file'
IOError: file too big for single read
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That message comes from [io.c, remain_size](http://www.ruby-doc.org/doxygen/1.8.4/io_8c-source.html#l01108). It is emitted when the (remaining) size of the file is greater or equal to `LONG_MAX`. That value depends on the platform your Ruby has been compiled with.

At least in Ruby 1.8.7, the maximum value for Fixnums happens to be just half of that value (-1), so you could get the limit by

```
2 * 2 ** (1..128).to_a.find { | i | (1 << i).kind_of? Bignum } - 1
```

You should rather not rely on that.

Comment: I had the same error while reading a 50 GB file, and the above gives 9223372036854775807 with Ruby 2.1.2 and 1.9.3, and even 1.8.7 on Linux.